# Illegal base64 data at input byte 4 when using base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(str)

Tags: go, base64

I am getting: error: `illegal base64 data at input byte 4`

When passing in Base64Image into `base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(str)`:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYA...
```

Let me know if you need the full base64, I have just pasted in the first part as it looks like the problem is within 4 byte?

```
data, errBase := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(Base64Image)
if errBase != nil {
    fmt.Println("error:", errBase)
    return false
}
```

Do you know why?

Comment: You need to strip off the "data:image/png;base64," prefix.

Comment: I had to strip off quotes around mine eg. "\"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYA..\""

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not all of your input string you try to decode is Base64 encoded form.

What you have is a [Data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), that provides a way to include data in-line in web pages as if they were external resources.

It has a format of:

```
data:[<MIME-type>][;charset=<encoding>][;base64],<data>
```

Where in your case `image/png` is the MIME-type, the optional charset is missing, and `";base64"` is a constant string indicating that `<data>` is encoded using Base64 encoding.

To acquire the data (that is the Base64 encoded form), cut off the prefix up to the comma (comma included):

```
input := "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYA"

b64data := input[strings.IndexByte(input, ',')+1:]
fmt.Println(b64data)
```

Output:

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYA
```

Of which you can now decode:

```
data, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(b64data)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error:", err)
}
fmt.Println(data)
```

Output:

```
[137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10 0 0 0 13 73 72 68 82 0 0 0 100 0 0 0 100 8 6 0]
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/oIrLZl698G).

Answer (score 13):

Also this may happen if you encoded using `StdEncoding` and trying to decode using `RawStdEncoding`

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes this happens if your base64 string is not properly padded with == at the end.

Answer (score 2):

It's because your string isn't in base64 until after the comma data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYA...

import "strings" and use split to get the half after the comma and then call decodestring with that.

```
import "strings"

data, errBase := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(strings.Split(Base64Image, "base64,")[1]))
if errBase != nil {
    fmt.Println("error:", errBase)
    return false
}
```

EDIT: made the split token `base64,` because it's more specific to your input.